# Can you use only single select to write this query?

Tags: sqlite, join, select

Question: Find the titles of movies that have been reviewed by at least two reviewers. Please write an SQL with only **one SELECT** and **without GROUP BY.**

here is a query with more than one select:

```
select title,"count(M.mID)" from (select M.title,count(M.mID) from movie M,rating R where M.mID=R.mID GROUP by M.mID) WHERE "count(M.mID)">=2
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cgcs.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a column like an `ID` in the table `rating` that distinguishes the reviewers, then you can do a self join of `rating` and join it to `movie`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.title
FROM movie m
INNER JOIN rating r1 ON r1.mID = m.mID
INNER JOIN rating r2 ON r2.mID = m.mID AND r2.ID <> r1.ID;
```

The 2nd join of `rating` will filter out the movies for which there is only 1 reviewer.